# WIX booking form

Tags: velo

I want to hardcode an email into a wix booking form.

As we all know, we do not usually want to enter an email when we are making a bookin, so I want to hardcode my email into this field, so I would receive all the notifications.

if that is not possble, I want to receive the same notifications that my cleints are receiveing, is this possible?
Or maybe it is possible to create a button that will automatically fill this field with an email I want